# How to compile a gvim from source using the latest version?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim, compile, build

I'm using Ubuntu. I performed the following commands in the vim source folder:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes
make
sudo make install
```

I have found that related posts but fail in Ubuntu 13.04.

Here is the error after do the .configure

```
checking --enable-gui argument... no GUI support
```

How can I let the system to find the GUI library? I have tried to do

```
apt-get build-dep vim
```

The gui lib should be included, but no luck what else can I do?

I have also tried

```
--enable-gui=<auto, gtk, gtk2, gnome2>
```

All of them show the same error no GUI support...

More update and try

```
kithokit@12:39:06 ~ $ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'vim' as source package instead of 'vim-gtk'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
```

vim-gtk can not be installed...

I have already installed build-dep vim, but also no luck to find the GUI library.

Comment: We can't read your mind nor your screen; what's the error you get? The basic steps look fine.

Comment: "I have found that related posts but fail in Ubuntu 13.04". What does it mean?

Comment: You had the effort to set a bounty on the question, yet you decide not to provide us one of the most valuable piece of info: the error message.

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient info provided. I have updated my question

Comment: Do you have the development packages for GTK2/GNOME2 installed? If configure can't find them it will not enable building with the GUI.

Comment: As @Heptite said you need to `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk`first.

Comment: no luck, please see my update on my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution from this page
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim

the problem i can't get the GUI lib is that i have build the vim without GUI before.

And i use `make clean` instead of `make distclean` to rebuild the vim with GUI even the GUI lib installed. so the solution would be

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim

make distclean

./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes

make

sudo make install
```

I hoep it can help others

Comment: Did you mean "distclean" and not "diskclean"?

Comment: change back . thx